# Python's requests.get(url) for a non dot com domain

Tags: python

I'm trying to check whether a URL is available.  I'm performing requests.get(url, verify=None) where `url=https://myapplication.load`.  Yes, the domain is actually `.load` and it's inside our VPN. The url is working but the requests.get method returns a connection error.  All my other `.com` urls that are also inside our VPN work just fine with the requests.get method.  Am I doing something wrong? Is there anyway to get around this?

**EDIT**

The specific error I get when using requests.get() is `ERROR:Certificate did not match expected hostname`

Comment: What happens if you `curl` that domain? What happens if you visit it in a browser? What is the actual error?

Comment: @cwallenpoole - thanks for the reply.  The URL works when I visit it in the browser and also works when I curl it (using -k to skip the SSL).

Comment: @cwallenpoole - the specific error I get is `ERROR:Certificate did not match expected hostname`.  I thought setting `verify=None` would allow me to bypass this.  Is there some other way?

Comment: You might try requests[security] instead of the default requests library.

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake.  I thought `verify=None` was the same as `verify=False`.  It's not.  I made the change and everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification), you can disable all verification this way:

```
requests.get('https://host.domain.local', verify=False)
```

Note it specifies `False`, and while `None` is falsy, this will not necessarily work depending on how check is done:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> False == False
True
>>> None == False
False
```